# Searching for postitions creating a random point and clicking on it

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking for a random set of coordinates on my screen to which i'm then needing my mouse to move to and to click. I think the algorithm is correct but for some strange reason it's not clicking on the required position.

Here's the algorithm:

```
var PX = Algorithms.randomInteger(X1,X2);
var PY = Algorithms.randomInteger(Y1,Y2);
var PXY = new Point(PX, PY);
```

Now I know this algorithm works. I have tested it on one of my tools but when I try to add it to my other tool and add a click command im getting stuck and the algorithm fails to operate correctly:

```
PX := Algorithms.randomInteger(1135,1312)
PY := Algorithms.randomInteger(121,258)
PXY := new Point(PX,PY)
Click, PXY Left, 1
Sleep, 10
```

Basicaly im trying to set up to find a minimap on my screen and click on a random location on the minimap.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Can you tag your question with the programming language you're using, it will gain better visibility ;)

Comment: Yh sorry will do that now its ahk language

Answer (score 0):

The [`Click`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Click.htm) command can't handle object input.

One approch would be to not use your `Point` object. (Assuming `PX` and `PY` contains only a number.)

```
Click, %PX% %PY%
```

With the `Point` object you can use temp variables...

```
x := PXY.X
y := PXY.Y
Click, %x% %y%
```

... or you can use the "single percent sign expression mode".

```
Click, % p.X " " p.Y
```

For more information regarding dereferencing see [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm#Variables).